# Linker Errors Facebook Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I added `PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions!)` and I got the 9 linking errors that I feel like many people have gotten before.

First time working with Facebook in an app and I added every framework, the header, and filled in the `info.plist`

I had to unwrap `launchOptions` so can someone help me out on how to get rid of these Mach-O Linker errors.

**Updated with error log**

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F(1)'
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/fabricemulumba/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit', framework linker option at /Users/fabricemulumba/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookUtils", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo15PFFacebookUtils in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Can you paste the part of the log where it fails to link?

Comment: I'd recheck the Parse and Facebook related frameworks, the dependency frameworks and also Clean the DerivedData folder before rebuilding it.

Comment: Updated the Facebook SDK now I'm left with just these two errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the old version of the Facebook's framework? I've just checked the library out that it does not have 
`ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)` class.

To check that you could use

> otool -L ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework/ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -arch arm64

or

> otool -L libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a -arch arm64

the output will be like this

`libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookUtils.o):
 libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o):`

and I've checked out all dependencies libraries they also dont have any FBRequest and FBSession classes.

Try to use newest versions of sdk or link dependencies by CocoaPods.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought I used the newest framework but I'll check.

Comment: ParseFacebookUtils is from Parse SDK not Facebook